# WSL and ext4 : the disk remains full

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, disk, ext4

I'm using a Linux subsystem to run a numerical simulation software. This software generates fairly large files that I later delete in "Linux/Ubuntu/home/~/...," but my disk is still full.

When I look at my disk folders, there is a location called "ext4.vhdx" with a size of 320 GB, and it doesn't get cleared when I delete my Linux files.

I've tried emptying the trash, but I can't find anything in ".local/share." I attempted to restart the computer to refresh, stopped the WSL with the "wsl --shutdown" command, but nothing has worked.